# Can I use Saxon over org.w3c DOM model?

Tags: java, dom, saxon, w3c, xpath-2.0

On our project, we have our own implementation of org.w3c.dom.* interfaces.

Does Saxon support evaluation of XPath 2.0 queries not over XML itself, but over instances of org.w3c.dom.* instances?

Comment: See https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/thirdparty.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. You can use either the JAXP XPath interface or the s9api interface: we recommend s9api because the JAXP interface was never designed for the richer data model of XPath 2.0, for example there is no way to return a sequence of strings.

Saxon is quite a bit slower when running over a DOM than when using Saxon's native TinyTree model, by a factor of 5-10. Of course if it's your own implementation of the DOM, then (a) performance may vary, and (b) there's always a risk of bugs, e.g. your DOM might be 100% conformant to the DOM spec but still behave differently from any DOM implementation that Saxon has been tested with.

Saxon-EE 9.8 introduced a new way of handling navigation of DOM trees called the Domino model. This incurs an up-front cost in building indexes for the DOM tree in order to give improved performance on subsequent navigation. Don't use this if the DOM is mutable (that is, if the contents change between one XPath expression evaluation and another) because such changes will invalidate the indexes.